# WCF Concurrent Connections and Azure Service Bus Relay

Tags: wcf, azure, concurrency, azureservicebus

I have a WCF service listening to the Azure Service Bus Relay which for reasons I cannot change I am self hosting in a Windows Service.

Once the service is put under concurrent load - typically by giving it a series of long running requests - we start to receive the following messages back from the Azure Service Bus:

```
<Error>
<Code>502</Code>
<Detail>Bad Gateway.TrackingId:f0e32d08-2721-464c-a108-fe63f1efc443_G23,TimeStamp:4/23/2013 8:22:18 AM</Detail>
</Error>
```

We suspect concurrent load causes this problem.

My service is completely stateless.

```
ServiceHost = a WebServiceHost which we instantiate ourselves.
Binding = BasicHttpRelayBinding
InstanceContextMode = Single
ConcurrencyMode = Multiple
SessionMode = NotAllowed
ServiceThrottlingBehaviour.MaxConcurrentConnections = A very large number
Transport = Streaming
```

I have four questions:

1. Does the above error seem like a concurrent load issue?
2. What other configuration options should I be looking at to offer greater scale.
3. In a self hosted Window Service environment what happens when the concurrent connections limit are hit? Will the service just fail? Will connections be queued?
4. Is there a way that I can reliably monitor the number of concurrent connections at any given moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an employee on **Azure Service Bus Relay**.

I just ran a query to track down your issue. (*For future reference, it would have been much easier if I'd know the namespace you were using.*)

It appears that the **ServiceHost Listener** was not detected as connected to Service Bus when the 502 request was attempted.

The easiest way to debug this is to hook [`ConnectionStatusBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.connectionstatusbehavior.aspx) up to your endpoints and to hook up the `OnFaulted` event on the `ServiceHost`.

Also note that it is possible for specific VMs within Service Bus to go offline for short periods of time. When this occurs, your `ServiceHost` may appear to be offline for ~5-15 seconds. The best way to avoid this is to always ensure you host (2) `ServiceHosts` in separate processes/AppDomains so any single VM outage will not impact your service. (*This is very similar to website hosting recommendations.*)

If any issues that are unexpected occur after following these recommendations, please contact me directly at `toddreif@microsoft.com` so we can investigate.

Comment: Hi Todd, Thanks for your reply. We have been using the ConnectionStatusBehaviour to diagnose our connection and have not monitored any connection events during this time. It is currently a public holiday in Australia but I shall take you up on your offer and contact you with further details when I return to work. Thanks again.